# Need output in separate lines- Shell Script

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, output

I wrote this script for logging emails if disk-space is more than 90. Please help me get the output in separate lines. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

errortext=""

EMAILS="abc@xyz.com"


for line in `df | awk '{print$6, $5, $4, $1} ' `
do

# get the percent and chop off the %
percent=`echo "$line" | awk -F - '{print$5}' | cut -d % -f 1`
partition=`echo "$line" | awk -F - '{print$1}' | cut -d % -f 1`

# Let's set the limit to 90% when alert should be sent
limit=90

if [[ $percent -ge $limit ]]; then
    errortext="$errortext $line"
fi
done

# send an email
if [ -n "$errortext" ]; then
echo "$errortext" | mail -s "NOTIFICATION: Some partitions on almost 
full"         $EMAILS
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to save output in variables, and don't try to iterate over output from commands when you don't need to.

```
#!/bin/bash

mailto=( abc1@xyz.com abc2@xyz.com )
tmpfile=$( mktemp )

df | awk '0+$5 > 90' >"$tmpfile"

if [ -s "$tmpfile" ]; then
    mail -s 'NOTIFICATION: Some partitions on almost full' "${mailto[@]}" <"$tmpfile"
fi

rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

This mails the relevant lines of the `df` output to the addresses listed in the `mailto` array if there are any lines whose percentages exceeds 90%.  The `0+$5` will force `awk` to interpret the fifth field as a number.  The `-s` test on a file succeeds if the file is not empty. `mktemp` creates a temporary file and returns its name.

Comment: @AnkkurSingh If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).